# Mouse right double click in Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, dom, angular

Is there a built in `event handler` in Angular2 for `double right click`?

I doubt that there is a DOM event which handles such behaviour and I'm aware that a workaround with `mouseup` event is possible.

Answer (score 3):

No browser supports a double right click natively, and I would avoid handling such an event since most users would not expect it to work. A right click is often referred to as a context menu click because that's what it is for.

Comment: I agree, but we are in 2016 and Web Apps are getting very much attention now.
I see dblrightclick(fast and precise) as important as swipe on mobile apps.

Comment: What is the use case? I can't imagine how it would be useful but now I'm curious.